# How can I get the name of the previous activity and store in a variable

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an app where I have many activites. And when the user ends interacting with the content of each activity it launchs an Activity called WellDone! where the user can see the average of the lessons (it's a course). 100% completed and it has a button for the next lesson. I want to get the name of the previous activities for example activity_lesson1, activity_lesson2 to show in a TextView to have a Title.
When ends the lesson1 it launchs the WellDone! Activity and I want to set in a TextView (title) the name of the lessons that have just learned.

```
package com.flixarts.ar.**;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class welldone extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView title;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantallanextsesion);

        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tituloActivity);

        title.setText() //Here the title of the previous activity that have come from intent
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that the answer to the literal question is "no" - you cannot get the name of previous activity. But there's probably another way to accomplish what you need.

If these are all your activities, why not put an extra in the Intent (when going in the forward direction) which says which activity it is coming from.

You can then decide what name of the activity to display based on checking that extra, which should tell you what the previous activity was.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use SharedPreferences, which allow you to easily save some String value in one activity and read it in another. In previous activity e.g activity_lesson1 you could override method onPause (or onDestroy if you finish your activity while proceeding to next one by calling finish() method) and save the name of activity as String like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("LAST_ACTIVITY_NAME", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    editor.apply();
}
```

Then you can read saved value inside WellDone activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String lastActivityName = sharedPref.getString("LAST_ACTIVITY_NAME", "default_value");
    title.setText(lastActivityName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to pass previous activity name

**Use Intent**

**FirstActivity**

```
 String TAG=FirstActivity.class.getSimpleName();

 submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name=nameEt.getText().toString();
            mobile_number=mobileEt.getText().toString();
            Intent intent=new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("Last_Activity_Name",TAG);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**SecondActivity**

```
  String lastActivityName;
lastActivityName=getIntent().getStringExtra("Last_Activity_Name");
```

**use SharedPreferences **

**FirstActivity**

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("Last_Activity_Name", TAG);
editor.apply();
```

**SecondActivity**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String lastActivityName = sharedPref.getString("Last_Activity_Name", 
 "default_value");
title.setText(lastActivityName);
```